# Export a presentation to pdf with one slide and its notes per page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I would like to export presentations to pdf with one slide and its notes per page.

I know how to export a presentation to PDF using the Drive API but I don't see how I could specify that I want to see the notes too because at this stage it is just a file.

Yet it is possible to do this via the UI so there must be a way...

Do you actually have to create a new document with the image of the slides in the top half of each page and its notes in the bottom half and export that to pdf?

Comment: For more people to help, you should say you are using the "Google Slides API" in the question and details of the problem. I had no idea until I noticed the tag underneath. And if you are using the API you should display the sample code you are using for feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I comprehend that your goal is to make a PDF out of a Slide with this format: first, you want the slide itself; and on its bottom you desire its associated speakers notes. If my comprehension is correct you can use the following functions to reach your intention:

```js
function fromSlideToPDF(slideID) {
  var docID = DocumentApp.create("Brief Doc").getId();
  var docBody = DocumentApp.openById(docID).getBody();
  var slides = SlidesApp.openById(slideID).getSlides();
  var requestAuth = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var requestURL = "https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/" +
      slideID + "/pages/" + slides[i].getObjectId() + "/thumbnail";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestURL, requestAuth);
    var thumbnailURL = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var thumbnailBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(thumbnailURL.contentUrl, requestAuth)
      .getBlob();

    docBody.appendImage(thumbnailBlob).setWidth(611).setHeight(344);
    docBody.appendParagraph(slides[i].getNotesPage().getSpeakerNotesShape()
      .getText().asRenderedString())
    docBody.appendPageBreak();
  }

  DocumentApp.openById(docID).saveAndClose();
  fromDocToPDF(docID);
  DriveApp.getFileById(docID).setTrashed(true);
}

function fromDocToPDF(docID) {
  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(docID);
  var PDF = doc.getAs("application/pdf");
  var folderID = doc.getParents().next().getId();
  var request = {
    title: "PDF of " + doc.getOwner().getName(),
    parents: [{
      "id": folderID
    }],
  }
  Drive.Files.insert(request, PDF);
}
```

For clarification purposes I am going to describe the approach of that code. The main function is `fromSlideToPDF()`, which converts from Google Slides to PDF requesting only the ID of the presentation. It will first create a dummy Doc with [`.create()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app.html#createname) and get its body with [`.getBody()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html#getbody), and read the the slides of the original presentation using [`.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app#openbyidid) and [`.getSlides()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getslides). It will then iterate each slide and requests its thumbnail to be included into the dummy Doc. Under each thumbnail the script will add its linked speaker notes too. After the iteration is completed, the function will save the changes in the dummy Doc with [`.saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose).

The second function will be called then to convert the dummy Doc into the final PDF. To accomplish that, it will read the Doc as a PDF with [`.getAs()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getascontenttype) and its first parent folder (please, note that a single file can be hosted in different folders) with [`.getParents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents) and [`.next()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator.html#next). The script will then extract the parent folder ID with [`.getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder.html#getid). Finally, that second function will build and execute a file upload request as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#uploading_files).

After the second function converts the dummy Doc to a PDF file in the same folder, the first function will delete the dummy file with [`.setTrashed()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed).

Finally I want to mention that I am using two different advanced services, for [Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides) and [Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides), to execute API requests from Apps Script. Refer to the linked documentation for instructions on how to activate these services on the script editor.

Please, take this as one of the possible solutions to your issue, and don't hesitate to write me back with any doubts or requests for further clarification.